# Kernel Module worker threads not stopping on kthread_stop

Tags: c, linux, semaphore, kernel-module

I was helping someone troubleshoot why a kernel module worker thread was not stopping correctly on module exit.  I have never done any module development before, so I created a hello world example for troubleshooting and no luck.  Below is the code for a simple module that spawns off a thread that then blocks on a mutex.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/sched/signal.h>
#include <linux/semaphore.h>

struct semaphore mutex;
struct task_struct *sample_thread_handle = NULL;

int sample_thread(void *arg)
{
   printk(KERN_INFO "Starting Thread...");
   while(!kthread_should_stop())
   {
      if(down_interruptible(&mutex)) {break;}

   }
   printk(KERN_INFO "Leaving Thread...");
   return 0;
}

static int __init my_module_init(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, world!\n");
    sema_init(&mutex,1);
    down(&mutex); // grab the mutext to keep the thread from exiting
    sample_thread_handle = kthread_run(sample_thread,NULL,"sample thread");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit my_module_exit(void) 
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "stopping sample thread\n");
    kthread_stop(sample_thread_handle);
    printk(KERN_INFO "after stopping consumer thread\n");   
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, world!\n");
}

module_init(my_module_init);
module_exit(my_module_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Your name");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple kernel module");
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");
```

The initialization grabs the lock to simulate the worker thread being blocked on the mutex when it is being shutdown.  From looking at examples, the thread attempting to acquire the lock using the `down_interruptible(&mutex)` call should allow it to be interrupted by the `kthread_stop` method, but I must be misunderstanding something as the rmmod call just hangs and never shows the log Leaving thread...  Any nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick look ...

1. In `my_module_init`, you're doing `sema_init` and then `down`.
2. In `sample_thread`, you're doing `down_interruptible`, so it blocks [on the first iteration].
3. The "interruptible" means that the call can be resumed if the process receives a *signal* (i.e. it has a *pending* signal).
4. `kthread_stop` does *not* signal the target thread, so *no* signal to wake up the thread.
5. `kthread_stop` *does* do a `wake_up_process` but [AFAICT] that just marks the thread runnable (and schedules it).
6. But, once running [again], the `down_interruptible` loops and rechecks the mutex and goes back to sleep.

Where's the `up(&mutex)` call???

*Side note:* You're using single global variables for `mutex` and `sample_thread_handle`. Maybe okay for a *simple* test. But, I'd put those in a `struct` and pass that as the thread argument.

Comment: 1. Yes, it was intentional to simulate the case where the workder thread blocks at a semaphore waiting for data to be placed on a buffer for processing.

Comment: 2. I was mistakenly (based on your statement on 4) that the kthread_stop would “interrupt” the down call and allow it to complete.  I am more of a c# developer and am used to using cancellation tokens to cancel blocking calls, so I am a lot out of practice on what is available with what c exposes to you a the kernel level.

Comment: Yes, I cringe on globals, but it was done for the sample.  The actual module code was too large, and filled with business logic outside of the issue.  This shows the same thing.  I guess I need to change the pattern on how to block a consumer while waiting for more data, bit allow it to cleanly exit with asked to.